# Can Only Access Site Via Localhost

Tags: webserver, plesk

Have a have a Windows VPS using Plesk 9.

Until today I have been using the http://myIPaddress:8443 method of accessing Plesk Panel but now I can't access via a browser.

This is the Google Chrome error (Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error).

If I use an RDC connection and open a browser window and connect via http://localhost:8443 it works just fine.

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other services installed on different ports?  Can you see if those work?

Has your connection changed at all (firewall/router)?

Comment: Not aware of any other services on other ports. This is a fresh server. Had access yesterday - none today??

Comment: To follow up the last point, just turned off the firewall and it makes no difference. There is a site under construction on the server and I can't access that via a browser either (could yesterday).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ERR_CONNECTION_RESET indicates that the communication between your browser and your server is cut short, in effect, your browser is asking your server "What's up!" and before your server can respond, the communication drops.

This can be several things. It could be the firewall on your server. It could be a firewall on your internet connection and/or PC or it could be your ISP itself.

If you have the ability to try a different ISP (maybe even from a different PC, like an internet cafe) to test that it's not on your end, you can eliminate any software on your PC or your own network from this almost instantly.

Using RDP and being able to access your Plesk installation on the server itself indicates that there's nothing wrong, it could be as simple as just a piece of software you installed or setting you changed by accident. (Peerblock sometimes block's communication that's legitimate)

The last thing you can check is (if you're running IIS, which I assume you are) to check on the website settings which IP addresses, for that installation, is allowed. It could be that it's set to 127.0.0.1, by default I'd keep it to listen on all IP addresses if I were you.

Otherwise, if you've checked from a different ISP and computer and you're still not able to access it, I'd recommend submitting a support ticket with your hosting company to double check the installation.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how do I check the settings for the IP addresses. I only have a small amount of knowledge in this field. I am not able to access a properties option on a right click on the site. This is IIS7 on a Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Glad you came right, I had to go for a few hours and only noticed your question. To answer it (for others as well) on IIS7, you need to click on "Edit Bindings" to the right hand side of the screen after you selected the website. A popup will come up and it will give you the option to edit the entries; where you will then choose a specific IP or "all unassigned" to make it choose automatically.